# Why aapt dump badging doesn't work on Linux

Tags: android, aapt

I'm using aapt to dump info from apks, it works fine on Mac, but failed on Ubuntu.

Here is the log from the two machine:

Mac:

```
$ md5 test.apk 
MD5 (/Users/jlee/tmp/test.apk) = 022d63fa0e3e9f10f57550d8921088d9
$ aapt dump badging test.apk 
package: name='com.i9i8.nanopage' versionCode='46' versionName='1.2.18'
application: label='MoreGoodNews' icon='res/drawable/mushroom.png'
launchable activity name='com.i9i8.nanopage.StartupActivity'label='MoreGoodNews' icon=''
sdkVersion:'3'
targetSdkVersion:'7'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
main
other-activities
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
locales: '--_--' 'zh' 'en'
densities: '160' '240'
```

Ubuntu(10.04):

```
$ md5sum test.apk
022d63fa0e3e9f10f57550d8921088d9  /home/jlee/tmp/test.apk
$ aapt dump badging test.apk
ERROR getting 'android:versionName' attribute: attribute is not a string value
package: name='com.i9i8.nanopage' versionCode='46' 
$
```

Both aapt are from the lastest android-1.6 platform, which on Linux is android-1.6_r03.

I also tried the following version of aapt on Linux:

```
android-1.5_r04-linux
android-2.0_r01-linux
android-2.1_r02-linux
```

None of them works.

Is this a bug of aapt? Or something that I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well I am begginer at android but, did you set you .bashrc file ? I mean did you set correcly you path to android-sdk/tools , you can also try to lunch the shell and navigate to android-sdk/tools folder and after that type the aapt dump badging test.apk. I don't think that this is your problem but I think that yours problem is also strange like mine, I mine problem was that I had installed android-sdk twice and one of the versions was broken. So commands from shell worked strange because the path was pointing to the old (broken) installation.
When you find solution about this please post it here
Thanks